# HTML из raw в assets + чтение этих файлов

Tags: java, html, android, webview

Всем доброго времени суток! И так. У меня есть **ListView** с множеством итемов, по нажатию определенного я подгружаю определенный html файл из папки **raw**.  Но сейчас я имею необходимость переместить все файлы из папки raw в папку **assets**, но не знаю, что мне нужно поменять в коде для правильного чтения из папки **assets** (чтения (не открытия) именно всех файлов для последующего открытия нужного), исходя из моего кода.
Код:

В методе onCreate

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
    String resName = "file:///android_asset/" + "file" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
    Log.i("name", resName);
    Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

    //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "my_package_name"));

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

Код чтения из raw-ресурсов:

```
 public static String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Пробовал множество методов чтения файлов, предложенных ресурсами интернета и, в частности, на англоязычных вопросах **stackoverflow**. На каждый метод находился по одной-две ошибки, а половина мне и вовсе не подошла, так как там был метод для чтения и открытия уже одного файла, когда мне нужно чтение **всех** файлов, почти тоже самое, что у меня сейчас, но из папки assets.

Answer (score 1):

Решил сделать по минимализму. Получилось! Намного-намного проще, чем я думал.
К собачьим чертям удалил все после строки:

```
String resName = "file:///android_asset/" + "file" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
```

И сделал такой вид:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + resName + ".html");
```